# 'For Next' loop to perform action based on worksheets with similar names

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of worksheets with similar names and want to perform an action for all of these worksheets (e.g. sheet names are `1C`, `2C`, `3C` etc.).  I've tried the following code but I'm getting *Run-time error 424*:

```
Sub InsertURLType()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastCol As Integer

For Each ws In Activebook.Sheets

If ws.Name Like "?1" Then

    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    Columns(LastCol).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "URL Type"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],URLs!C1:C2,2,FALSE)"
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Range(ActiveCell.Address, Cells(LastRow, ActiveCell.Column))

End If

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no `Activebook` that I know about. Try `ActiveWorkbook` as in the [ActiveWorkbook property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821871.aspx).

Comment: Excuse me. Your worksheet name are (1C,2C,3C) or (C1,C2,C3)? You can use `"C" + right(ws.name)` or `left(ws.name) + "C"` for condition check at line `if ws.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Activebook` that I know about. Try `ActiveWorkbook` as in the [ActiveWorkbook property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821871.aspx).

Further in, you should be dealing with the `ws` worksheet type variable that is set with for `For Each ... Next` loop. A [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) will allow all further operations to reference it as the worksheet to have work performed upon.

```
Sub InsertURLType()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        With ws

            If .Name Like "?1" Then  '<~~ this doesn't appear to pattern match the WS names you described in your narrative

                LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<~~ look from the bottom up

                .Columns(LastCol).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                .Cells(1, LastCol) = "URL Type"
                .Cells(2, LastCol).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], URLs!C1:C2, 2, FALSE)"

            End If
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

The mask you are using for `If .Name Like "?1" Then` doe not appear to match the worksheet names you provided in your narrative. If this doesn't work out, provide a list of all of the worksheet names along with a subset of the ones you want to work on.

This short sub will check your worksheet names.

```
Sub Check_WS_Names()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, strWSs As String

    strWSs = " 1C 2C 3C 4C 5C 6C 7C 8C 9C 10C 11C 12C 13C" & _
             " 1O 2O 3O 4O 5O 6O 7O 8O 9O 10O 11O 12O 13O" & _
             " 1S 2S 3S 4S 5S 6S 7S 8S 9S 10S 11S 12S 13S "

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        With ws
            If CBool(InStr(1, strWSs, Chr(32) & .Name & Chr(32), vbTextCompare)) Then
                Debug.Print "found: " & .Name
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Check the VBE's Immediate window (Ctrl+G) for the results after you have run it.

Comment: Sorry about that, I accidentally wrote the ws name mask wrong.  It was in the vba as ?C, not "?1".  The code you have given me unfortunately didn't work.  When I've used your code, and when previously amending mine, the For Next statement does not pick up on any of the worksheets.

Comment: I should also mention that I tried the exact name of the first worksheet "1C" and the code did not find the sheet and just kept looping through the For...Next statement.

Comment: Regarding the worksheet names, there are 42 worksheets in this workbook.  The sheets which I need to insert formulas into are named "1C, 2C, 3C....through to 13C".  There are also two other sets of sheets with similar naming structure "1O, 2O, 3O... through to 13O" and another set named "1S, 2S... etc".  In addition to these are are some other worksheets used for analysis (used for charts and lookup tables etc)

Comment: Sorry but I cannot see any way that the loop cannot find each worksheet in the [Worksheets collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224508(v=office.11).aspx). I just stripped out all of the nested If... End If and it reported every ws name in the workbook I threw it into.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question (I'm very much an amateur at this). I'm finding that when I type "worksheets." and the members of the object pops up that "name" is not an option.  Would this have anything to do with my problem? Is there some basic code I could use to just search and activate a sheet? i.e. If worksheet.name is "1C" then activate cell "A1" and msgbox "found worksheet"?

Comment: You are confusing the [Worksheets collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224508(v=office.11).aspx) with individual [Worksheet objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224506(v=office.11).aspx). The latter has a Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx), the former are all of the worksheets in the workbook.

Comment: Please see the short `Check_WS_Names` sub I added to the reply above.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm not sure what has happened or exactly what I was doing wrong before but your code is performing the action as I need it to. I am getting _Run-time error '1004'_ at step `.Cells(2, LastCol).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], URLs!C1:C2, 2, FALSE)"` but as mentioned, it has completed the actions I wanted it to and inserted the formula so I'm unsure why this has occured

Comment: Glad you got sorted out. As this post-question discussion has been getting a little elongated, perhaps it's time to close this question off by accepting one of the replies as the answer and starting a new question if you run into future problems.